# Do I need to replace this valve that a plumber claimed needed to be replaced?

Tags: plumbing, valve, replacement

We have this pipe that cracked, and we wanted to fix it. One plumber claimed not only does the pipe need to be fixed but this shut off valve also needed to be replaced.

Mind you, he made this claim, simply from looking at this same image. What do you guys think? I don't know what kind of valve this is, but all he said was this valve would eventually fail and needed to be replaced with the same job. Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Where is the crack? If the valve was exposed to the crack it may be damaged, or he may have suggested replacing it based on age. A 1/4-turn ball valve would typically be used in a spot like this, these older valves are less reliable. If you're already replacing adjacent pipes, it would probably be a good idea to replace this valve now as well.

Comment: It is a shut off valve.  It only needs to be replaced if it is not doing it's job or leaking.  It is old and might fail soon, and if he is working on the pipe anyway, it should only add a few bucks to the job.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based. If I was a plumber and was going to spend an hour or two doing this job I absolutely would not want to work with or reinstall a crusty POS valve that can (and should) be easily replaced for a few more bucks. It's a pain to do the job with old parts, and it's more likely to lead to a callback if not done.

Comment: @crip659 _Few_ $55 extra bucks.

Comment: Paint the valve; stops people moaning about it. Close and open the valve occasionally; keeps it in working order

Comment: @OutdatedComputerTech they're [$10 at Lowe's](https://www.lowes.com/pd/AMERICAN-VALVE-Lead-Free-Brass-Gate-Valve-NPT/1000330507). I have no idea where you're getting $55 from, unless you're telling us what your plumber is telling you, in which case it probably also includes labor.

Comment: @Chuck $10 for the valve and $45 for installing it?

Comment: @chuck everything lowes sells is not good quality. Had a person at Home Depot tell me the Watts Brand was good. I Don't know what to believe. And I'm willing to buy a good quality part if I can find one. This debate about whether to replace or not to replace is the dilemma I face. I'd be willing to spend $50 on a simple valve if I knew it was going to last 30 years.

Comment: Nothing is going to last outside for 30 years without maintenance, and the amount of rust on the valve says to me that you're not maintaining it. Does it work? Is it your only shutoff? It doesn't need to be replaced unless it leaks, but if the rest of your plumbing is shot to the point that it's leaking, how much more life do you think you have on this?

Comment: @JoshPart - yeah, $45 for installing it. Do you see the rust on it? What are the odds the threading on the valve inlet hold up? If the inlet pipe fails, do you see enough sticking out of the wall to be cutoff and coupled? What's on the other side of the wall? Does the water to the house need to be shutoff and the whole house bled down? It's really quite a lot of risk touching something in a condition that poor. Keep in mind too that the plumber is discussing this at all because other piping has already rusted completely through when weighing risk.

Comment: Wish I could get a plumber to install a new valve for $55 here in NOVA...I was quoted $250+, even as part of other work!

Comment: You misunderstand, the cracked pipe is a specific price, just to replace that valve aswell, they wanted an extra $55. Anyway the guy that was going to do this job, never showed up, blocked my calls and I found someone else cheaper. Plumbers don't like small jobs, they want big money jobs. Shrug. That's why I said extra...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it needs to be replaced.  It is severely corroded and will probably fail when the pipe is replaced. It looks to be a 3/4 inch gate valve, and a new one will be cheaper than having to take the piping apart again later.

Comment: Yes, have it replaced. It looks like it's a compression fitting to a copper pipe, minutes to remove and replace.

Comment: Also, spend a few extra dollars to put in a quarter-turn valve. The older compression valves tend to get to be very hard to turn if they have not been operated in a while (common on shut off valves).

Comment: In general whenever I address old plumbing I always replace old gate valves. New high quality valves are cheap and simple to install. The plumber's time is expensive and shutting down water is annoying.

Comment: Save the valve. Worth cleaning and replacing the packing if needed. Valve quality today suffers compared to valves produced 30 years ago. I cringe at the number and differing types of valves I've pitched over the past 30 years just to learn they could have been rebuilt for less than the cost of a cup of coffee.

Comment: @davidC.rankin Planned Obsolescence. This exactly why I posted this question. The valve works fine. And always in the open position. Yet almost everyone here wants me to replace it. I'm going to replace it with an inferior valve, which troubles me. I've replaced a ton of outdoor faucets to a quarter-turn Ball valves. 2 of 6 of which have already failed within 3-4 years. REALLY, I can only depend on a ball valve for 4 years max now?  All valves are made in china (it seems) and they are poor quality no matter what. I'm assuming this is what plumbers want. To keep the money rolling in.

Comment: @Matthew where are these cheap high quality valves you speak of? I'm all ears.

Comment: I'm a victim of experience here. I have a home built in 68 and an office built in the 50s. The valve quality of the original valves were incredible (many lasted 40+ years). Up to about 2005 I could still find decent brass valves. Most made right here in town [Nibco, Nacogdoches, TX](https://www.nibco.com/Employment/Texas-Nacogdoches/) Since then with all the hardware stores closed in favor of big-box stores, if I can find the valve I need -- it's total inferior crap. Thankfully all exterior faucets were frostless - so I was forced to rebuild those. Old brass is better brass.

Comment: @OutdatedComputerTech "always in the open position", but it's a cut-off valve and is there for a reason. Does it work reliably now? Will it do so when needed?

Comment: @CGCambell I agree. The answer is, I dont know! haha. I'm willing to replace it, just not with an interior product that's going to fail in 3 years.